# Duplicating a row and changing one word

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains data similar to the following

[image]

```
ID  Created Username    Email   Dept    PW
1   01/01/2021 07:00    admin       a   werfv
2   02/01/2021 07:00    George      a   rtyh
3   03/01/2021 07:00    Jane        a   earg
4   04/01/2021 07:00    Admin       b   sdfbrgsth
5   05/01/2021 07:00    George      b   sdgrf
6   06/01/2021 07:00    Mike        b   sthjyu
7   07/01/2021 07:00    admin       c   drytdyt
8   08/01/2021 07:00    jenny       c   aregerg
9   09/01/2021 07:00    admin       d   erte453
10  10/01/2021 07:00    harry       d   argkjtyui
```

now I need to change every line where the user is admin to make the user John and create new duplicate entries for username jason, liz, sally for that dept

there are 463 depts so manually doing this will take awhile

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           YT.dept,
           V.username
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES('jason','liz','sally')
    WHERE YT.username = 'admin')
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (dept, username)
SELECT C.dept
       C.username
FROM CTE;

UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET username = 'John'
WHERE username = 'admin';
```

Comment: Sorry struggling with this as my sql isnt brilliant.

there are 32 columns per line, do I not need to mention these? also you have v.username but where have you defined V?

Comment: Also I think I need to show a clean shot of table: (there are another 21 coumns but these just need to be the same in each row,

Comment: *"do I not need to mention these"* Yes, you would need to `INSERT` all the columns you need. Your example only has 6 columns, and I *assumed* that `ID` and `Created` are auto generated. `Email` is clearly `NULL`, so omitted, and password, well I have no idea where that comes from. As for the other 24, they aren't in your example, but this should be more than enough to get you there.

Comment: tx will work on this helps massively